# Passing by reference of objects created 'on the fly'

Tags: c++, reference

My apologies if this question has been answered already - I have searched, but it's a difficult search term to find due to the sheer number of more general questions on passing by reference.

The problem I have is that I am getting a level 4 warning when I compile this sort of thing:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {};
};

void DoSomethingToMyClass(MyClass& my_class_reference);


void MyRoutine()
{
    DoSomethingToMyClass(MyClass());
};
```

The warning (C4239) basically says that there is a dodgy cast from an instance to a reference.  I have learnt from careful inspection not to write-off level 4 warnings, as many of them have identified bugs in my (and others') code, such as returning -1 as a size_t (bonus points for knowing what size_t(-1) actually is).

Can anybody explain to me what the code above will actually do?  My most paranoid theory is that:

- An instance of MyClass() is created on-the-fly, but not given a proper handle.
- Operations performed on my_class_reference reference are then mis-firing.

The other extreme is that C4239 can always be ignored...

*[An analogous situation is when somebody defaults a reference:

```
void DoSomethingToMyClass(MyClass& my_class_reference=MyClass());
```

This generates the same warning, but is partially covered in another topic.]*

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the quick response, guys.  Sorry: should have mentioned it's VC++ in Visual Studio.

Comment: This is actually a proper error, but your compiler seems to be a bit lax about the rules.

Comment: It can misfire also if you store the passed reference somewhere and it will be then freed immediately after returning to MyRoutine.

Comment: So MS might have frigged it a bit to allow this to work correctly, but it probably shouldn't...

Comment: MS being Microsoft in this instance, not me (Mike Sadler), of course...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the warning because that's not standard C++, but a MS extension that allows you to bind temporaries to non-`const` references.

Just don't. Either have the parameter a `const` reference:

```
void DoSomethingToMyClass(const MyClass& my_class_reference);
```

which might not apply here, as the name implies the method mutates the class, or create the object beforehand:

```
MyClass x;
DoSomethingToMyClass(x);
```

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm trying to remove the warnings on other peoples' existing code.  The frustrating thing is that when I try to create the object beforehand and pass it in, in some cases I get some very strange other problems.  Part of this is because one of the instances of this also accepts a reference to a base class which cannot be instantiated :-(

Comment: @MikeSadler regarding your last sentence, if it a non-instantiable base class, then you can't very-well do this either: `DoSomething(NonInstantiableBase())`. So you must be passing *something* that either can be created on-the-fly, or is already created somewhere else, and if it can be created on-the-fly, it can be created as Luchian shows in this answer.

Comment: @MikeSadler so just pass an instance of a derived class, no?

Comment: Just that: one of a variety of derived classes was being passed in (ErrorMessage, WarningMessage, etc).  The function expected a ExceptionBase& - and because ExceptionBase is abstract, you can't pass in by value, as you can't copy it.  It's not my code, but looked OK at first glance, but now it seems over-complicated.

Comment: @MikeSadler I'm not saying pass it by value. By reference is good, just not a temp. `MyConcreteClass c; DoSomethingWithClass(c);` where the method takes a `MyBaseClass&` as parameter.

Comment: @LucianGrigore I've done that in several cases, but that also failed in some cases (still trying to figure that one out).  I've actually fixed it by making the reference 'const' - and made all the dynamic_casts used in the body of the function cast to const versions as well.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a temporary nameless object through `MyClass()` and as per the C++ standard temporary objects cannot bind to non constant references. Hence the warning.
Some compilers do allow this as language extensions.

So either:
You need to change your interface to take a const reference to bind to an temporary.

```
void DoSomethingToMyClass(const MyClass& my_class_reference)
                          ^^^^^^^
```

or don't pass an temporary nameless object pass an named object.

```
void DoSomethingToMyClass(MyClass& my_class_reference);

Myclass obj;
DoSomethingToMyClass(obj);
```

Comment: Will the const binding guarantee correct behaviour?  I intuitively feel more confident if it is a const, but that doesn't neccesarily mean that the temporary handle is safe.

Comment: @MikeSadler: It is safe. Binding an temporary to an const increases lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of the reference itself. Good read: [Most Important const](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/)